# Validate 2 models in 1 form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-forms

I'm learning RoR and I can't find a way to validate my models in the same form. It is validating, but it only shows the error messages of one model (address) and it's filling the other input fields of the other model like it was before the changes were made. I tried a few things but none of them worked.

In the edit.html.erb I'm showing the error messages. This works fine only if one model is not correct. If the input in both models are not correct, I only see the error message of address and the input fields of mutuality are reset with the previous values.

I think this is all you really need. My address controller is empty. Everything else is working fine except the validation.

Mathias.

### Edit.html.erb:

```
<h1>Edit Mutuality</h1>

<%= form_for @mutuality do |f| %>
<%= fields_for @address do |fa| %>
    <% if @mutuality.errors.any? %>
        <h2>Errors:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @mutuality.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
    <% if @address.errors.any? %>
        <h2>Errors:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @address.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= f.label :name %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= f.label :phone %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= f.text_field :phone %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= f.label :contact %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= f.text_field :contact %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= fa.label :street %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= fa.text_field :street %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= fa.label :number %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= fa.text_field :number %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= fa.label :zipcode %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= fa.text_field :zipcode %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= fa.label :city %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= fa.text_field :city %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= f.submit %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

### Controller:

```
class MutualitiesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @mutualities = Mutuality.all
  end

  def show
    @mutuality = Mutuality.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @mutuality = Mutuality.new
    @address = Address.new
  end

  def create
    @mutuality = Mutuality.new(params[:mutuality])
    @address = Address.new(params[:address])

    if @address.save
      @mutuality.address_id = @address.id
      if @mutuality.save
        redirect_to mutualities_path, :notice => "Mutuality saved with succes!"
      else
        render "new"
      end
    else
      render "new"
    end    
  end

  def edit
    @mutuality = Mutuality.find(params[:id])
    @address = Address.find(@mutuality.address_id)
  end

  def update
    @mutuality = Mutuality.find(params[:id])
    @address = Address.find(@mutuality.address_id)

    if @address.update_attributes(params[:address])
      if @mutuality.update_attributes(params[:mutuality])
        redirect_to mutualities_path, :notice => "Mutuality updated with succes!"
      else
        render "edit"
      end
    else
      render "edit"
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @mutuality = Mutuality.find(params[:id])
    @address = Address.find(@mutuality.address_id)
    @mutuality.destroy
    @address.destroy
    redirect_to mutualities_path
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails can handle nested-attributes automatically. You are doing it all manually.
Not sure if you have defined the associations in your model correctly.

So, in your model you should write:

```
class Mutuality
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

and in your controller you can then just write:

```
def create
  @mutuality = Mutuality.new(params[:mutuality])

  if @mutuality.save
    redirect_to mutualities_path, :notice => "Mutuality saved with succes!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make the thing work! I made the changes that Nathanvda told me, but I had to add a few things to make it work. There's still one tiny problem. I can't manage to delete the address. It only deletes the Mutuality. Any ideas?

### Address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :street, :number, :zipcode, :city
  attr_protected :id

  has_one :mutuality

  validates_presence_of :street, :number, :city

end
```

### Mutuality.rb

```
class Mutuality < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :phone, :contact, :address_id
  attr_protected :id, :address_id

  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true

  validates_presence_of :name, :phone, :contact
  validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 5
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

end
```

This is the link I use on the show.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <%= link_to "Back", mutualities_path %> |
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_mutuality_path %> |
    <%= link_to "Delete", @mutuality, :confirm => "You are going to delete " +  @mutuality.name + ". Do you wish to continue?", :method => :delete %>
</p>
```

And here's the destroy function:

```
  def destroy
    @mutuality = Mutuality.find(params[:id])
    if @mutuality.destroy
      redirect_to mutualities_path, :notice => "Mutuality deleted with succes!"
    else
       redirect_to mutualities_path, :error => "A problem has occured."
    end
  end
```

Mathias